# Can't figure out why I'm getting java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to create a java program that would take an input amount and output the change with fewest coins. Although when I run my program I get the desired output, I get a unit testing error for the method Change. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalamount;
        int[] coins = new int[] { 100, 25, 10, 5, 1 };
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        totalamount = s.nextInt();
        Change(totalamount, coins);
    }

    public static void Change(int totalamount, int[] coins) {
        int[] amount = new int[5]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            if (totalamount >= coins[i]) { 
                amount[i] = totalamount / coins[i]; 
                totalamount = totalamount % coins[i]; 
            } 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            if(amount[i] != 0)
            System.out.println(amount[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

and this is the unit testing error I get:

```
Change(300, coins)
Your output
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Comment: At some point `coins[i]` is zero

Comment: What is `coins` in your test?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Inputting any number will always work, as the coins are always `{100, 25, 10, 5, 1}` -> please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Off topic but in the Change method use `coins.length` when initializing the `amount` array and in the for loop

Comment: Show filing test.

Comment: I assume this is homework or some on-line challenge/test and that you haven't written the unit tests yourself so please add the full requirements for this assignment.

Comment: it all works  https://ideone.com/E5nmsQ are you sure, you are not running wrong class?

Answer (score 2):

coins[i] must be zero at some point. Check your data. To safeguard, put an additional check for coins[i]

```
if (coins[i] > 0 && totalamount>= coins[i]) { 
...
}
```

Comment: I checked.. It isn't zero at any point

Comment: Are you getting the same error even after putting the additional check? Why don't you post the contents of coins[]